# FTPS protocol version

Tags: java, ftps

I'm trying to connect to a ftps server, but I have all the time the SSL Exception "Received fatal alert: protocol_version". I modified my code 1000 times searching for the right implementation but its the same error every time (my jar is running in java7)

What I tried:

- Java8
- Changing the java panel control to accept different TLS version
- Connect with explicit mode and set port 21.

my code :

```
public FTPConnection(String host, String username, String password, boolean passive) throws IOException {
            this.host = host;
            System.setProperty("jdk.tls.useExtendedMasterSecret", "false");
            System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
            this.clientFtps = new FTPSClient("TLS", false);
            try{
            this.clientFtps.connect(host, 21);
            }catch (SSLException e){
                log.debug(" port : " + this.clientFtps.getDefaultPort() + " Reply : " + this.clientFtps.getReplyString());
                log.debug("catched exception : " + e);
            }
            if (username != null)
                try{
                    if (pasv) {
                        this.clientFtps.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    } else {
                        this.clientFtps.enterLocalActiveMode();
                    }
                    this.clientFtps.login(username, password);
                    log.debug(this.clientFtps.getReplyString());
                }
            catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
                this.clientFtps.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                this.clientFtps.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                log.debug("the type of ftp file is : " + FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        }
```

my error :

> catched exception : javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version

what the server return :

> https.protocols : TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
> port : 21 Reply : 234 AUTH TLS successful

Comment: Try with `-Djavax.net.debug=all`. You might need a pager for the output or redirect it to a log file. I would personally set those networking properties at the command line so you can change them later. Perhaps do the debugging with none set to begin with

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried that but gave me nothing. I installed Wireshark and i get this error "550 TLS handshake Failed " 
Response code: Requested not taken: File unavailable (550)

Comment: Difficult to know without running it myself. One thing you don't want is this: `log.debug("catched exception : " + e);` Don't concatenate the exception to a string. You need to log the stack trace